# How Do I Insert Data Into Shopware 6 Database Via The Administration

Tags: vue.js, shopware6

I have created a plugin, created an admin route but inserting the data into Shopware 6 database does not work. Below is my code. After the build process, it doesn't work, what am I doing wrong?
From the code below I am trying to insert the data 'Diekedie' into the 'name' column of the 'product_manufacturer_translation' table.

```
const { Component, Mixin } = Shopware;
import template from './custom-module-list.html.twig'
Component.register('custom-module-list', {
  template,

  inject: [
   'repositoryFactory'
   ],

  metaInfo() {
     return {
         title: this.$createTitle()
     };
   },

 data: function () {

   return {
       entity: undefined
   }

  },

  methods: {

   manufacturerRepository() {
       return this.repositoryFactory.create('product_manufacturer_translation');
   }
   
  },


  computed: {
   
},

created() {

   this.manufacturerRepository();

   this.entity = this.manufacturerRepository.create(Shopware.Context.api);

   this.entity.name = 'Diekedie';

   this.manufacturerRepository.save(this.entity, Shopware.Context.api);
}





 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set translations you use the repository of the related entity, not the repository of the translations themselves. Also if you have a method that returns the created repository, you must use that return value to create the entity:

```js
methods: {
   manufacturerRepository() {
       return this.repositoryFactory.create('product_manufacturer');
   },
},

created() {
   const repository = this.manufacturerRepository();

   this.entity = repository.create(Shopware.Context.api);

   this.entity.name = 'Diekedie';

   repository.save(this.entity, Shopware.Context.api);
}
```

Comment: It works. PS, you must be connected to the internet too.